# Dúvida função def com entrada em modo tuple

Tags: funções, python-3.x, tupla

Bom pessoa eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
    def tuplas(x):

        return x[::2]

tuplas(('Hello', 'World', 'estamos', 'vivos'))
```

Este código vai funcionar perfeitamente, porém se eu retirar os parênteses da minha tupla, obviamente o python vai dar error:

```
TypeError: tuplas() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Obviamente devido há eu ter definido apenas um argumento na função, é na verdade claro eu teria que ter inserido um argumento para cada item da tupla. Eu que inserindo os dados em modo string "Hello World estamos vivos" é dando um split terei sucesso mais a saída será como string e não uma tupla.

A dúvida é possível eu inserir meu dados na forma de tupla não colocando os parênteses ex: 'Hello', 'World', 'estamos', 'vivos' com apenas um argumento na função def tupla(x), não me questionando para eu colocar os outros argumentos é esta saída for na forma de tupla mesmo.

a função seria a seguinte:

```
    def tuplas(x):

        return x[::2]

tuplas('Hello', 'World', 'estamos', 'vivos') # desse modo da error
```

Ou não teria como, eu teria que colocar os parênteses para o python reconhecer isso como tupla.

Espero ter sido claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma sintaxe especial que permite a você receber um número variável de informações em uma função:

```
>>> def tuplas(*args):
...     return args[::2]
... 
>>> tuplas('Hello', 'World', 'estamos', 'vivos')
('Hello', 'estamos')
```

Comment: Perfeito @marcelo-theodoro funcional 100%